# How to detect the origin of a stack overflow error in Pure Data

Tags: stack-overflow, puredata

I'm dealing with a stack overflow error on a big patch in Pure Data and I would like to know how can I see the object which is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

most error-messages in the Pd-console are clickable to take you to the object that raised the error.

either

- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>LeftClick</kbd> on OSX)

OR

- position the cursor on the error message and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>

will take you to the object that emitted the error.

Note however, that a *stack overflow* usually occurs because you have some too-deep recursion in your patch, and *any* of the involved objects might emit the error. That is, the object you will find is not necessary the cause of the problem (it's just the bearer of bad news), but at least you have a starting point where to look for.